# SQL Query using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max, having-clause

Write a query to display Department_ID and maximum salary of all employees whose Department_ID is greater than 10 and having a maximum salary greater than 20000 for each department. Display the data in descending order with respect to Department_ID.

```
select Department_ID, max(Salary)
from employees
where Department_ID > 10
having max(Salary) >20000
order by Department_ID DESC;
```

This is my query but it only displays one result. Since the question asks for each department, I am sure my query is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

You need a `group by` clause to make your query a valid aggregation query (in many RDBMS, you would get a syntax error):

```
select department_id, max(salary) max_salary
from employees
where department_id > 10
group by department_id
having max(salary) > 20000
```

Answer (score 3):

You are  missing the group by

```
   select Department_ID, max(Salary)
    from employees
    where Department_ID > 10
Group by Department_ID
    having max(Salary) >20000
    order by Department_ID DESC;
```